# Using CSV Data config file in jmeter-maven

Tags: java, maven, csv, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am currently working on a project using jmeter-maven plugin. I need to use a CSV data config file from which some variables are to be read during execution. Although the created JMX file works in the JMeter GUI, the same isn't working in non-gui mode.
From the logs, I was able to gather that the data file isn't being opened (stored) during execution in the non-gui mode, which on the other hand, it happens in the GUI mode leading to successful execution in GUI mode.

I have checked the path of the file (the absolute path of the file - with forward slashes), permissions of the file and all the parameters set in the CSV data config element in the jmx file created (it has proper path to the csv file) and I couldn't possibly get the reason on why the CSV file is not being used during execution in non-gui mode.
I have tried having the CSV file in the bin folder (giving the complete path of to the bin folder and just the file name - both methods), having the csv in the same path as the jmx file.

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

[CSV Config Data CSV configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ZIj.jpg)

Comment: Can you show you CSV Data Set config ? Can you show the error in jmeter.log ?

Comment: There is no error in the logs. As i said, since the Data file wasn't read during execution, all the APIs that are parameterized with variables are failing. @UBIKLOADPACK

Comment: Placing the CSV Config Data Set config element inside each ThreadGroup solved the issue. But isn't placing the same outside all ThreadGroups a more efficient way? Placing outside all ThreadGroups must also allow access to all right?